# Dynamically referencing database tables with php variable

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I am trying to select columns from tables stored in an Oracle database inside a php script. Tables should be referenced dynamically by a php variable.

What I currently have and what is working:

> $query = "SELECT table_name.id AS xyz FROM table_name";

What I want is:

> $name = "table_name";
>
> $query = "SELECT $name.id AS xyz FROM $name";

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @Kaddath Bad manipulation is not possible in my case because the variable $name is set by the user by selecting a table_name from a drop down list. If I post the second query with the $name variable I defined above, I retrieve the following warning: Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00936: Statement missing in C:\xampp\htdocs\bbplaene.php on line 71. I guess this means that he cannot correctly interpret my second query.

Comment: @Kaddath I can be absolutely sure. The webiste is for internal use (intranet) only and each user will only be interested in a unique value of that variable. So, misuse is nothing to worry about here.

Comment: $query = "SELECT $name.id AS xyz FROM $name"; it should work fine ..?

Comment: First why is this tagged MySQL and not Oracle? Second, please post **full** error and not in comments. Please post actual **full** code block and not line snippets,. Finally, edit your post in describing the tables as it feels non-normalized (i.e., an employee table for each employee, jobs table for each person).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your contributions!
As @Mahesh Hegde pointed out, the query was correct. Strangely, I had to save my script under a different name to make it work ;)
I also included the changes you proposed @Kaddath.